# Octomap with turtlebot

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, octomap, octomap-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Has anyone used Octomap with turtlebot. I see there are no tutorials on the octomap. So i just wanted to know if someone successfully used it for their work and could give me some heads up on the same.

I would like to create a 3D occupancy grid map of the surroundings using the kinect on the turtlebot and navigate on the same.

Any suggestions and pointers are much appreciated!!!

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29017/octomap-with-turtlebot/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-03-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out [octomap_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap_server) and its documentation. That's what you need to build up 3D occupancy maps from any point cloud source. There is an example launch file in the package which you only need to modify. It should be straightforward if you have good odometry or a localization in a 2D map running along.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ketan Katkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/11536/ketan-katkar/) on 2014-06-03**:
how is the odometry done in octomap? is it visual odometry ? how can we link another (good) odometry with octomap ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should work just fine; the Kinect generates point clouds, just as you'd expect.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-03-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-03-04**:
Mac, thanks for the response. Could you guide me through the same. A tutorial page would be too much to ask, but it would be of great help.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-03-04**:
Sure can't; dig around on octomap, I suppose.